# nestjs node module issue, How to use when/sequence module in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I writing a code in nestjs. I am using the when module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/when) in my project.

I am importing when module as follows

```
import { sequence } from "when/sequence";
```

but when I print the sequence. it gives value as undefined. for that reason, not able to use when a module in nestjs
any idea here how to import and install node module in nestjs

Comment: the last release of this package was in 2017 lol I think you can replace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `when` [only compiles to CommonJs and AMD.](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/installation.md) Therefore, it doesn't allow the `import .. from "..."` syntax introduced in `ES6`.

You should import it is using `require()`.

```js
const sequence = require("when/sequence")
```

Comment: same issue. I am using node 14.17.5. is there any other way here?

Comment: @SurajDalvi but you can use node 14.17.5 without using ESM. But if you want to use ESM, then read this https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { sequence } from "when/sequence.js";
```

or use [dynamic imports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions) to load CJS modules:

```js
const { default: sequence } = await import("when/sequence.js");
```